# Buscar menor posicion en un array de Strings

Tags: array, c, string, position

hice el siguiente codigo para que yo pasandole por parametro:
-Los datos validos de un array de string
-La posicion desde la cual yo quiero empezar a comparar
-La matriz de tipo Char con los strings

La misma funcion me **deberia retornar la posicion del menor string pero no me funciona, alguna idea?**
Esta es la llamada a la funcion: vcadena son la cantidad de strings que tiene, 0 es la posicion desde la cual quiero empezar a recorrer, cadena es la matriz de strings

```
    int menorPos = buscarMenorPosString(vcadena,0,cadena);
```

Aca les dejo la funcion

```
int buscarMenorPosString (int v, int pos, char matriz [][MAX_LONGITUD])
{

    char menor = matriz[pos];
    int menorPos = pos;
    int i = pos+1;

    while(i<v)
    {
        int x = strcmpi(menor, matriz[i]);
        if(x==1)
        {
            menor = matriz[i];
            menorPos = i;
        }

        i++;
    }
    return menorPos;
}
```

Comment: Lo que quieres es la posición de la cadena más corta?

Comment: No, necesito la posicion de la cadena de menor valor alfabetico

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que no este en lo correcto, pero para copiar una cadena en C, no tendrías que utilizar strcpy?

int buscarMenorPosString (int v, int pos, char matriz [][MAX_LONGITUD])
{

```
char menor = matriz[pos];
int menorPos = pos;
int i = pos+1;

while(i<v)
{
    int x = strcmpi(menor, matriz[i]);
    if(x==1)
    {
       strcpy (menor,matriz[i]);
        menorPos = i;
    }

    i++;
}
return menorPos;
```

}

Fijate si así compila!